# Using Crypto Obfuscator to embed DLLs with inheritance

Tags: c#, dll, obfuscation, embedded-resource, crypto-obfuscator

I am working on a project where we are using Crypto Obfuscator to embed several DLLs into a single DLL. Then the DLL is loaded dynamically in another project into its own app domain. Most of the embedded DLLs seem to work correctly. However any embedded DLL that contain classes that the main DLL classes inherit from do not to load correctly. The only way I have gotten this to work is to leave the DLLs in the directory (which defeats the purpose of embedding them).

For Example:

I have four different DLLs: MyLibrary, MyLibrary2, MyProgram, and MyInterfaces

*MyClass1* class, in the MyLibrary DLL, inherits from the interface *ClassInterface* inside of the MyInterfaces DLL.

*MyClass2* class, in the MyLibrary2 DLL, inherits from *MyClass1*. Crypto Obfuscator is used to embed the DLLs: MyInterfaces and MyLibrary inside of the MyLibrary2 DLL.

*MyProgramClass* class, in the MyProgram DLL, has a reference to the MyInterfaces DLL and uses it to dynamically create an instance of *MyClass2*.

When the program runs it will complain that it cannot find the assembly MyLibrary when it tries to create the instance of MyClass2.

*Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

Any ideas how to solve this?

MyInterfaces DLL:

```
namespace MyInterfaces
{
    public interface ClassInterface
    {
        string Get();
    }
}
```

MyLibrary DLL:

```
namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class MyClass : MarshalByRefObject, ClassInterface
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "2.0.0.0";
        }
    }
}
```

MyLibrary2 DLL:

```
namespace MyLibrary2
{
    public class MyClass2 : MyClass, ClassInterface
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return base.Get();
        }
    }
}
```

MyProgram DLL:

```
namespace MyProgram
{
    public class MyProgramClass
    {
        public MyProgramClass()
        {
            try
            {
                string typeName = "MyLibrary2.MyClass2";
                string appDomainName = "MyLibrary2";

                ClassInterface c2 = CreateInstance(@"X:\Temp\MyLibrary2.dll", typeName, appDomainName);

                if (c2 == null) return;

                MessageBox.Show(c2.Get());
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show(":(");
            }
        }

        private ClassInterface CreateInstance(string filePath, string typeName, string appDomainName)
        {
            try
            {
                AppDomainSetup appDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

                if (!fileInfo.Exists) return null;

                appDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath = string.Format("{0}", fileInfo.Directory.FullName);
                appDomainSetup.PrivateBinPathProbe = "True";

                appDomainSetup.ApplicationBase = fileInfo.Directory.FullName;
                appDomainSetup.ApplicationTrust = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ApplicationTrust;

                Evidence evidence = new Evidence(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence);
                AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(appDomainName, evidence, appDomainSetup);

                string assemblyName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.FullName);

                return appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assemblyName, typeName) as ClassInterface;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update 1**

I have looked into using the AssemblyResolve event. I have tried to implement it in my test application to see if I could get it to work. I placed a breakpoint inside of the AssemblyResolve Event, however it is never hit and the error is still thrown. If I setup *MyClass2* not to inherit from *MyClass1*, my breakpoint is hit and executes correctly.

As a side note, using JustDecompile on the DLL, that contains the embedded DLLs, it appears that Crypto Obfuscator sets this event up in the default namespace of the DLL.

I used to the following link to implement the AssemblyResolve event:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx

MyLibrary2 DLL Changes:

```
namespace MyLibrary2
{
    public class MyClass2 : MyClass, ClassInterface
    {
        static MyClass2()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;                
        }

        static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            String resourceName = string.Format("{0}.{1}.dll", "MyLibrary2", new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name);

            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];

                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);

                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }
        }

        public string Get()
        {
            return base.Get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try hooking [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); it's possible you can enumerate the loaded assemblies and point to an already loaded matching assembly.